# Column is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea when saving entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a problem saving entity with UUID field. I create a new instance, call `setMyGuid(UUID.fromString(guid));` and then call `save` method of my `CrudRepository`. But it produces SQL with column value `'<byte[]>'`, not UUID/String.

binding parameter [8] as [BINARY] - [d720f7e2-69ec-4646-bd99-72545123f873]

I have `hibernate.dialect` set to `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`, I've tried to set also `spring.jpa.database-platform`, but nothing helps. [Here is written](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#uuid-mapping-changes), that UUID should map to SQL uuid.

Database is Postgres, column definition is:

```
@Column(name = "my_guid", nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "uuid")
private UUID myGuid;
```

Stack trace with library versions is there:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "my_guid" is of type uuid but expression is of type bytea
  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 238
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.PreparedStatementSpy.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementSpy.java:1080) ~[log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1-1.16.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3327) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3965) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:653) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:283) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:53) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:737) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2.$Proxy138.persist(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:610) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: What's your Spring & Hibernate & Postgres versions?

Comment: Please see stack trace and my answer for versions and solution.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in Dialect class. Uuid is registered only if version is >= 8.2, but when I check what getVersion() returns, it's 8.0 (default). PostgreSQL server is 15.1.

```
protected void registerColumnTypes(TypeContributions typeContributions, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    if (this.getVersion().isSameOrAfter(8, 2)) {
                ddlTypeRegistry.addDescriptor(new DdlTypeImpl(3000, "uuid", this));
    }
```

You have to create Dialect class and specify version:

```
public class CustomPostgresDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect {

    public CustomPostgresDialect() {
        super(DatabaseVersion.make(15, 1));
    }
```

Comment: This should not be necessary.

Comment: Our project already has custom dialect to make HQL JPQL able to use postgres json arrow operator, so this solution is the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

We had this same problem, and for us the solution was to remove the specified `PostgreSQLDialect` altogether. Note that we are using Spring boot 3/Hibernate 6, and apparently Hibernate 6.x is a lot better at resolving the dialect by itself which is mentioned in the [migration guide](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/6.0/migration-guide.adoc#dialects):
`As of Hibernate 6.0, dialects can detect and adapt to the version of the database in use and its spatial capabilities.`

Comment: This looks like the right solution to me.

Comment: In your linked guide, they say that 'Use these dialects instead, and ignore their deprecated subclasses'. Use -> org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect , but as I have in my answer, it's not enough.

Answer (score 1):

We were also facing this issue. Removing the dialect did not work, and the accepted answer *seemed* to work.

However, we found that this property `use_jdbc_metadata_defaults` was set to `false` in persistence.xml.

Removing the property fixed the issue without the need to override dialect - In fact, we could remove the specified dialect and rely on Hibernate 6.x detection instead.

Comment: This solved it for me. Now to figure out why we had set that property to false in the first place.